# webpack style loader and css loader not working for simple example

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader

I attempting to follow the tutorial here https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/ however I can never get the css file to load. (the text is never red)

I have tried all available solution which was suggested on slack that is not working for me. Will you please help me to figure out it.

```
  dist/index.html
  dist/main.js
  dist/main.js.LICENSE.txt
  package.json
  src/index.js
  src/style.css
  webpack.config.js
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
  };
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import './style.css';


function component() {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
  
  // Lodash, now imported by this script
    element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');
    element.classList.add('hello');
  
    return element;
  }
  
  document.body.appendChild(component());
```

style.css

```
.hello {
    color: red;
  }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Asset Management</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle webpack-demo@1.0.0~prebuild: webpack-demo@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle webpack-demo@1.0.0~build: webpack-demo@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle webpack-demo@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle webpack-demo@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\User\Desktop\Interview Ninja\elasticsearch\webpack-demo\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.352.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Python311\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3\bin;;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs
9 verbose lifecycle webpack-demo@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Interview Ninja\elasticsearch\webpack-demo
10 silly lifecycle webpack-demo@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack' ]
11 silly lifecycle webpack-demo@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle webpack-demo@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: webpack-demo@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid webpack-demo@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\Desktop\Interview Ninja\elasticsearch\webpack-demo
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.17.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error webpack-demo@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the webpack-demo@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, is this issue happening on your local, or on the build generation or on the deployment cloud pipeline?. Can you give more context please. Now can you please go the index.js file was built and check the path to the style.css generation. To validate if is a path issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second `module.exports` in your Webpack config file and try again.